# Creating namespace for jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider i am having 2 plugins. Namely tooltip, popover.

Now i call these function, like this

> $('#target').tooltip('create');
>
> $('#target').popover('hide');

But i want to create a common namespace for these function , so that i can call them like this

> $('#target').mynamespace.tooltip('create');
>
> $('#target').mynamespace.popover('hide');

I just cant figure out a way to do this

Comment: What's the point in doing that?

Answer (score 0):

To maintain `this`, you would need to either make your namespace another function:

```
$.fn.mynamespace = function() {
    var that = this;

    return {
        tooltip: …,
        popover: …
    };
};

$('#target').mynamespace().tooltip('create')
```

… or use a property, which looks better but isn’t supported by older browsers. Neither of these ways fit in particularly nicely with the whole jQuery syntax, though, so avoid if at all possible. (Consider, for example, just choosing more specific names.)